# Valor da variável em PHP

Tags: php, variáveis

Olá!

Recebo as variáveis assim:

```
&a25Item1=01&a25Prod1=00123&a25Desc1=ProdutoAcabadoUm
```

O número vai depender de `$qtdProd`

```
&a25Item2=01&a25Prod2=00123&a25Desc2=ProdutoAcabadoDois
```

Como em PHP eu faço a atribuição abaixo:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $qtdProd ; $i++){

    $a25Item i = $_GET['a25Item' i ];
    $a25Prod i = $_GET['a25Prod' i ];
    $a25Desc i = $_GET['a25Desc' i ];
}
```

Preciso que $a25Item receba a25Item juntando com o contador como se estivesse atribuindo:

```
$a25Item1 = $_GET['a25Item1'];
$a25Item2 = $_GET['a25Item2'];
```

E assim sucessivamente. Agradeço desde já!

Obrigado a todos! Funcionou assim:

$item = array();
$prod = array(); 
$quan = array(); 
$desc = array(); 
$prec = array(); 
$subt = array();

for($i = 0; $i <= $nCtd ; $i++){

$item['a25Item'.$i] = $_GET['a25Item'.$i]; 
$prod['a25Prod'.$i] = $_GET['a25Prod'.$i]; 
$quan['a25Quan'.$i] = $_GET['a25Quan'.$i]; 
$desc['a25Desc'.$i] = $_GET['a25Desc'.$i]; 
$prec['a25Prec'.$i] = $_GET['a25Prec'.$i]; 
$subt['a25Subt'.$i] = $_GET['a25Subt'.$i];

}

E para pegar os valores:

for($i = 0; $i <= $qtdItem -1 ; $i++){

$item['a25Item'.$i]. 
$prod['a25Prod'.$i]. 
$quan['a25Quan'.$i]. 
$desc['a25Desc'.$i]. 
$prec['a25Prec'.$i]. 
$subt['a25Subt'.$i];
}

Dessa forma consigo montar do jeito que preciso.Valeu! RESOLVIDO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize um `array` para armazenar os itens, podendo assim fazer isso:

```
$itens = array();
$produtos = array();
$descricoes = array();
for($i = 0; $i <= $qtdProd ; $i++){
  $itens['a25Item'.i]=$_GET['a25Item'.i];
  $produtos['a25Prod'.i]=$_GET['a25Prod'.i];
  $descricoes['a25Desc'.i]=$_GET['a25Desc'.i];
}
```

A chave para acessar o valor será por exemplo: `$itens['a25Item0'], $itens['a25Item1']`, isso retornará os valores passados pelos `$_GET['a25Item0'], $_GET['a25Item1']`

Para acessar os itens:

```
foreach($itens as $item => $chave){
  echo $item;
  echo $chave;
}
foreach($produtos as $produto => $chave){
  echo $produto;
  echo $chave;
}
foreach($descricoes as $descricao=> $chave){
  echo $descricao;
  echo $chave;
}
```

Lembrando que talvez existam outras opções melhores.

Answer (score 2):

Não é possivel criar variáveis definindo o seu nome como se fosse uma `string` e a concatenação de `string` em `PHP` não é desta forma:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $qtdProd ; $i++){
    $a25Item i = $_GET['a25Item' + i ];
    $a25Prod i = $_GET['a25Prod' + i ];
    $a25Desc i = $_GET['a25Desc' + i ];
}
```

Uma forma que pode ser útil para você e acredito que seja melhor, é fazendo assim:

```
$arr = [];
for($i = 0; $i <= $qtdProd ; $i++){
    $arr[i]['a25Item'] = $_GET['a25Item' . i];
    $arr[i]['a25Prod'] = $_GET['a25Prod' . i];
    $arr[i]['a25Desc'] = $_GET['a25Desc' . i];
}
```

Você estaria salvando os dados em uma `array` onde a `key` iria ser o valor de `i`. E para cada posição na `array`, `$arr[i]`, você teria uma outra `array` com as informações que você precisa, como: `a25Item`, `a25Prod` e `a25Desc`.

**OBS:** Acredito que seria melhor nomeá-los apenas como: `item`, `prod` e `desc`.

Em relação a concatenação de `string` você faz da seguinte forma:

```
$_GET['a25Item' . i]
```